# Perlin noise grid transformation question

Tags: javascript, p5.js, translate, noise

Objective: Amend the `compassGrid()` function to create a grid of 25x25 lines of length `stepSize`. Make sure each compass is at the center of each tile. By default they should all be pointing up. You should use `translate()` to move to the center of each grid.

I've tried all kinds of stuff, but none of my attempts seem to reach the objective outlined above. Here’s my code:

```js
var stepSize = 20;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function draw() {
  background(125);
  colorGrid();
  compassGrid();
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function colorGrid() {
  for (var x = 0; x < width; x += width / 25) {
    for (var y = 0; y < height; y += height / 25) {
      let from = color(255, 0, 0);
      let to = color(0, 255, 0);
      let interA = lerpColor(from, to, n);
      var n = noise(x / 50, y / 50, frameCount / 100);
      var c = map(n, 0, 1, 0, 255);
      fill(interA);
      stroke(c);
      rect(x, y, stepSize, stepSize);
    }
  }
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function compassGrid() {
  translate(10, 10);
  for (var x = 0; x < width; x += width / 25) {
    for (var y = 0; y < height; y += height / 25) {
      push();
      translate(x, y);
      stroke("black");
      line(0, 0, 0, stepSize - 5);
      pop();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.js"></script>
```

What's my mistake?

Comment: Other than the `lerp` third variable issue that p5 provides the solution to, things look pretty reasonable here. Can you clarify the problem with the output exactly?